# UI5 sap.m.SplitAppMode.ShowHideMode switch mode not working

Tags: master-detail, sapui5

I want to `hideMaster` page in "Master Details" template. My master page is getting hide using `mode="HideMode"` in app.view, but how can I show it again on click details page button.

Note: I have one header button in details page.

App.view

```
<SplitContainer id="idAppControl" beforeMasterOpen="changeMode" mode="HideMode">
```

controller.js

```
var oSplite = new sap.m.SplitApp("idAppControl", {});
oSplite.backMaster();
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can control Master Page from controller.**

For example, I wanted to hide Master Page after navigation to details:

App.view

```
<SplitApp id="idAppControl" mode="HideMode" afterMasterNavigate="onAfterMasterNavigate" afterDetailNavigate="onAfterDetailNavigate" />
```

App.controller

```
onAfterDetailNavigate: function(oEvent) {
    oEvent.getSource().hideMaster(); //Hide
},
```

If You want to display Master Page use bellow method 
(You can call it in button event or something else)

```
oEvent.getSource().showMaster(); //Show
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, I tried all posibilities to show Master page but not getting.. can u share one example or any reference link.

Comment: @MS' I checked it. This methods works only for "afterMasterNaviagate" and "afterDetailNavigate". So You can hide/show Master Page after navigation.

Looking for method to manipulate throught Detail Page.